# Can I write software using Unreal Engine 4 without compiling Unreal Engine 4 from source?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I just watched a video on YouTube: [Introduction to UE4 on GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usjlNHPn-jo&index=14&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gafGBkGkyB1JRFnUM2703YH)

Basically explaining how to get the Unreal Engine 4 source code from GitHub and how to build it in VS2013.

Now I understand the need for this if people want to make modifications to the engine itself, but if I want to use the engine as is and just program games with it, do I need to do all this?

I'm building it right now (75 minutes and counting), because I watched a UE4 programming tutorial and noticed that I was missing a few things that the programmer in the tutorial had (thought maybe because I didn't compile the Engine). I figured I needed to build the Engine because another UE4 programming tutorial said "I assume you have already downloaded the engine source from GitHub and compiled it in VS2013", nobody says why, nobody clearly states whether or not this is required to make a game in C++ using Unreal Engine 4.

Answer (score 2):

No you dont need the whole engine. There is a difference between the code which builds the editor and the code which builds your game. If you only want to program your game you should create a new "*code project*" and modify the code you're getting after creating the new project.